# How do I limit user to input a single character only in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, eof, stringstream

I am a beginner and I'm trying to limit the user to input a single character only, I do aware of using `cin.get(char)` and it will only read one character from the input, but I don't want the other characters be left in buffer. Here is a sample of my code using EOF, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <sstream>
     using namespace std;

     string line;
     char category;
     int main()
     {
         while (getline (cin, line))
         {
             if (line.size() == 1)
             {
                 stringstream str(line);
                 if (str >> category)
                 {
                     if (str.eof())
                         break;
                 }
             }
             cout << "Please enter single character only\n";
         }                  
     }
```

I have used this for digit inputs and the eof works fine.
But for the `char category` the `str.eof()` seems to be false.
Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eof flag is only set if you read try to read *past* the end of the stream. If `str >> category` read past the end of the stream, `if (str >> category)` would have evaluated false and not entered the loop to test `(str.eof())`. If there was one character on the line you would have to attempt to read *two* characters to trigger eof. Reading two characters is far more effort than testing the length of `line` to see how long it is.

`while (getline (cin, line))` got the whole line from the console. If you don't consume it in the `stringstream` it doesn't matter, that stuff is gone is gone from `cin` when you loop back around in the `while`.

In fact, the `stringstream` isn't doing you any favours. Once you've confirmed the length of the line that was read, you can just use `line[0]`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line; // no point to these being global.
    char category;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        if (line.size() == 1)
        {
            //do stuff with line[0];
        }
        else // need to put the fail case in an else or it runs every time. 
             // Not very helpful, an error message that prints when the error 
             // didn't happen.
        {
            cout << "Please enter single character only\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot, but do you know why does the returned eof value is 0?

Comment: @JohnDeveraux updated answer to explain why `eof()` didn't work.